# How to draw game on Android Canvas with lots of primitives

Tags: android, canvas

I draw a lot of lines rectangles each frame in my game - it's a recreation of an old school handheld electronic game. The ones that had crude dot matrix display for the main game and custom images for text or some images.

I have 20x20 big "pixels" on a virtual dot matrix screen, I also draw some 7-segment displays on the screen and some other things.

According to TraceView, most of time is spent at drawLine and drawRectangle methods, because there is simply too much of them. I draw each 'pixel' of the dot matrix display, and each segment of 7-segment displays in *every* frame.

An optimization came to my mind, that I would repaint only those pixels/segments which changed, so I have saved the previous state of pixels/segments and tried to repaint only changed ones. Basically it's a crude invalidation.

**The behavior I was expecting was that the Canvas would stay as it was after the last frame finished painting, and I would only repaint necessary stuff.**

Alas, my Canvas was flickering to black and every once in a while when state of my screen changed, only pixels of dot matrix display/segments flickered on for a frame. And I made sure that I didn't Clear my canvas.

I'm drawing on a Canvas inside a SurfaceView, updating Thread, as is described in Lunar Lander Android sample. In the Lunar Lander sample, they repaint everything in each frame.

Maybe I could render everything to a Bitmap on the first frame, then update that Bitmap on every other frame?

**Which technique should I use for my paint() method?**

Comment: What is the driving requirement to draw every pixel of a dot matrix?  Why not create a image file and draw that to your screen.

Comment: I have an array of 20x20 pixels on the screen that can either be turned on or off. If I fill a rectangle or draw a sprite, it's the same.

Comment: it seems that SurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost() clears my Canvas..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost() actually does page flipping on the Surface, so even if the previous frame wasn't cleared out you'd get the 2nd oldest frame, not the one you just drew. and doing lock() on a surface instantiates a new canvas each time which probably is doing the clearing in its constructor.

You're better off drawing into a Bitmap like someone suggested and then drawBitmap on the canvas each time you want to present the image to the display. You can aquire a canvas from a bitmap to draw into it

and like someone else suggested (very ambiguously), you can generate sprites for the dot matrix display and draw those directly from a cache of bitmaps rather then draw with primitive commands. ie for a dot matrix calculator you could generate all 0-9 into 10 bitmaps and simply blit them on the canvas rather then calling a set of drawLine/Rect operations.

if the above are still too slow there still is opengl, which takes advantage of hardware acceleration

Comment: ok, I'm drawing to a Bitmap on every frame, this way it retains the previous state. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not to go for [Sprites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29)?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What would using sprites change?

Comment: I think what is meant by sprites is basically what cris.h said, to put each possible image (e.g. numbers 0-9) in a small bitmap (sometimes called a sprite) and blit the bitmap instead of drawing it each time. This is likely to be faster because copying a bitmap (without scaling it) is usually faster than drawing a series of antialiased lines because the machine has to "think" less about how to do it. Some machines could have hardware acceleration for bitmap drawing, too.